# How to store nested lists as Django model field (or should I keep data as flat files)?

Tags: django

I'm working on a basic django web app (as a novice) that amalgamates several sources into nested lists representing flat 2d tables of data. This are then updated/displayed/referenced accordingly.

My current setup, which works ok, is for these data files to exist as very small csv files which are read/written as needed. They are also picked up using d3.js which has been easier given the d3 templates tend to import from a static data file.

It feels incorrect to not be querying the database directly for all of this data - is there an issue with using flat csv files?

If I should be querying the database, how best to store/access nested list data within Django? I can't find much but have seen some vague references to  Serializers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you read/write you should store data in your database. You can create a model which corresponds to your csv. A nested list can be stored as a simple string (or alternatively, if you need to query the list directly you can create another model which will hold the values - but that's rather inefficient). As for importing/outputting csv with models, you can do that with a script of your own or use a library like [django-adaptors](http://django-adaptors.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Oh, and as far as I am aware of `D3.js` accepts `JSON` which is more flexible and better supported in `Django`.

Comment: Why do you say that using a foreign key to create a 1 to many relationship is inefficient?  Its good to build models that are relational.  It makes queries possible that wouldn't be otherwise

Comment: Yes that's right but I imagine the csv contains lists with numerical data like `"0,1,1", "2,3,5"`. If this is not the case and the values are categorical then sure that's the way to go.

Comment: It would be good to see examples of your data @samg86. and the code you use for reading, updating and displaying your data.